# C++ CListCtrl - GetItemData always returns 0

Tags: c++, mfc

I am facing an `MFC` (Microsoft Foundation Class) project on `VS2017(x86)`.
Using the function `CListCtrl::GetItemData`, I always get `0` value.

```
CListCtrl             ctl;
DWORD_PTR             res;

res = ctl.GetItemData(2);
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What problem? We neither know, what you expect, nor why. Please see [ask].

Comment: Sorry, I am a new user.
When i call the function GetItemData, for different input list values (1,2,3..), I always get "0" instead of a valid DWORD_PTR data.

Comment: If you are a new user, it would make sense to take the [tour] (which was recommended to you when signing up, but you ignored the advice). On to your problem: What you have described is likely the expected behavior. You never set the data associated with your listview items, and when asking for the associated data, you get the default value. The bug is in your expectations. You solve it by reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/using-clistctrl).

Comment: Bumping into this post long after it's been closed.  It would be nice if the SO community could nudge new users to set them up for success instead of making them feel like they never want to come back.

Answer (score 4):

Function [`GetItemData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfshke78.aspx#Anchor_53) is used to retrieve data for item for the list control you set with [`SetItemData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfshke78.aspx#Anchor_118). [`Attach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xb05f0h.aspx#Anchor_12) is `CWnd` function that attaches a Windows window to a CWnd object.